# HTTPS works with Chrome but not IE on most of desktops

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

A HTTPS website works perfectly with Chrome but not IE(v11). When accessed from IE on MOST of desktops, the message was:

```
This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address https://alre.ba:8443 is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.
```

We do have VERY FEW desktops where we can access the site with IE. 
All desktops and IE installation are of same version.

Comment: What IE Version are you trying it on?

Comment: I don't think the debug output from wireshark is really helpful since it omits too much information. Please provide the full packet captures instead (for example at cloudshark.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was two different update policy were applied to desktops, with majority of them containing the TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA cipher suite and a few don't. the latest IEv11 don't support TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA.